# Difference of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary, difference

I've searched quite a lot but I haven't found any similar question to that one.

I have two lists of dictionaries in following format:

```py
data1 = [
    {'id': 4, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 34, 40)},
    {'id': 4, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 34, 40)},
    {'id': 6, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 34, 40)},
    {'id': 7, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 16, 14, 21)},
]

data2 = [
    {'id': 4, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 34, 40)},
    {'id': 6, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 34, 40)},
]
```

**desired output:**

```py
final_data = [
    {'id': 4, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 34, 40)},
    {'id': 7, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 16, 14, 21)},
]
```

I want only dictionaries which are in `data1` and not in `data2`.

Until now when I found a match in two for loops I popped the dictionary out of the list but that does not seem like a good approach to me. How can I achieve desired output?

It doesn't have to be time efficient since there will be max tens of dictionaries in each list

---

Current implementation:

```
counter_i = 0

for i in range(len(data1)):
    counter_j = 0
    for j in range(len(data2)):
        if data1[i-counter_i]['id'] == data2[j-counter_j]['id'] and data1[i-counter_i]['date_time'] == data2[j-counter_j]['date_time']
            data1.pop(i-counter_i)
            data2.pop(j-counter_j)
            counter_i += 1 
            counter_j += 1 
            break
```

Comment: Where is your current implementation, and what's the problem with it?

Comment: `{'id': 4, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 34, 40)}` *is* in `data_2`, and is in the output

Comment: Yes but there are two same dicts `{'id': 4, 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 12, 34, 40)}` so one is in `data2` but the second one is in `final_data`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Current implementation is a mess and I am not sure if it works properly. I'll add it to the question

Comment: What's wrong with two for loops? Something like `d = []
for d1 in data1:
    for d2 in data2:
        if d1 == d2 and d1 not in d:
            d.append(d1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is not an issue, why not:

```
for d in data2:
    try:
        data1.remove(d)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

`list.remove` checks for object equality, not identity, so will work for dicts with equal keys and values. Also, `list.remove` only removes one occurrence at a time.

Comment: Okay, actually I did not know that could ever work. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe add an `if d in data1:` so there's no need for the try/except statement?

Comment: @yatu The old philosophical question: ask for permission or ask for forgiveness. I always considered it more Pythonic to favor the latter. Certainly a matter of taste, mostly. You save a line, all right =)

Answer (score 1):

schwobaseggl's answer is probably the cleanest solution (just make a copy before removing if you need to keep data1 intact).

But if you want to use a set difference... well dicts are not hashable, because their underlying data could change and lead to issues (same reason why lists or sets are not hashable either).

However, you can get all the dict pairs in a frozenset to represent a dictionary (assuming the dictionary values are hashable -schwobaseggl). And frozensets are hashable, so you can add those to a set a do normal set difference. And reconstruct the dictionaries at the end :D.

I don't actually recommend doing it, but here we go:

```
final_data = [
  dict(s)
  for s in set(
    frozenset(d.items()) for d in data1
  ).difference(
    frozenset(d.items()) for d in data2
  )
]
```

Comment: Decent explanation and a good approach for true set-like difference. Note that the flat `frozenset(..items())` approach doesn't work in general, as the dict values might not be hashable.

Answer (score -1):

you can go in either way:

Method 1:

```
#using filter and lambda function
final_data = filter(lambda i: i not in data2, data1) 
final_data = list(final_data)
```

Method 2:

```
# using list comprehension to perform task 
final_data = [i for i in data1 if i not in data2]
```

Comment: That would remove all occurrences of any object in data2, not just as many as actually occur there.

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that it removes duplicate dictionaries which I need to keep.